# Spark structured streaming query exception

Tags: spark-streaming

This is my streaming code

```
session = get_session(SparkConf())

lookup = '/Users/vahagn/stream'
userSchema = StructType().add("auction_id", "string").add("dma", "string")
auctions = session.readStream.schema(userSchema).json("/Users/vahagn/stream/")
inputDF = auctions.groupBy("auction_id").count()
print inputDF.isStreaming

inputDF.printSchema()
inputDF.writeStream.outputMode("update").format("console").start().awaitTermination()
```

After reading first file I'm getting error, which doesn't explain anything.
Any ideas ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vahagn/hydra/spark/structured_streaming.py", line 257, in <module>
    inputDF.writeStream.outputMode("update").format("console").start().awaitTermination()
  File "/Users/vahagn/Downloads/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/streaming.py", line 106, in awaitTermination
  File "/Users/vahagn/Downloads/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
  File "/Users/vahagn/Downloads/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 75, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: u'null\n=== Streaming Query ===\nIdentifier: [id = 2f4b442a-38f9-41f1-a3d4-52e0a48427c0, runId = b843f25f-4132-4d52-ae64-f3be5e85a3d9]\nCurrent Committed Offsets: {}\nCurrent Available Offsets: {FileStreamSource[file:/Users/vahagn/stream]: {"logOffset":0}}\n\nCurrent State: ACTIVE\nThread State: RUNNABLE\n\nLogical Plan:\nAggregate [auction_id#0], [auction_id#0, count(1) AS count#7L]\n+- StreamingExecutionRelation FileStreamSource[file:/Users/vahagn/stream], [auction_id#0, dma#1]\n'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved problem by downgrading java9 to java8.

Comment: Another point might cause this problem is the version of packages. When i upgrade my package from  '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.0.2'  to '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0' it also solved the problem.